# When Table ellipsis attr is assigned `true` will show black text box. How can I change styled for textbox background color?

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

I used

```js
<Table {...props} ellipsis={true} />
```

from Ant Design

It will show textbox when I hold the mouse on the table cell that text-overflow

[image: Ellipsis table column]

And then the problem is I cannot use right-click or press CTRL + SHIFT + C on this textbox to styled CSS.

I need to change the background and text color.
How to do that?

#### My environment

1. Browser to develop a web it is **google chrome**
2. **Ant design V.3**
3. **Styled Component**

Comment: Is this Table part of any library?

Comment: Ant Design and custom with styled component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed this problem.
I passed `columns` props with `render` property. such as
`render(): (_, record) => (<Popover trigger="hover">{record.value}</Popover>)`

### Code

```
const MyTable = props => {
   .
   .

  const columns = [
     .
     .
    { ... },
    { ... },
    {
      dataIndex: 'description',
      key: 'description',
      render: ((_, record) => (
        <Popover trigger="hover" placement="topLeft" content={record.description}>{record.description}</Popover>
      ))
    },
    { ... },
    { ... },
     .
     .
  ]

  return (
    <Table {...props, columns} />
  )
}
```

Now I can custom antd className by my styled component.
Yeah!!